# Polynomials over number field

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a number field (i.e. a finite extension of ${\Bbb Q}$), and ${\cal O}_K$ be its ring of integers.  If $f(x) \in K[x]$ and $f(x)^n \in {\cal O}_K[x]$ then do we have $f(x) \in {\cal O}_K[x]$?

The argument used in Gauss' lemma would not work because we no longer have unique factorization.

Comment: I assume you mean $f(x)^n\in\mathcal{O}_K[x]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is true.  If $f(x)^n\in \mathcal{O}_K[x]$, then $f(x)$ is integral over $\mathcal{O}_K[x]$.  But a polynomial ring over an integrally closed domain is still integrally closed (see, for instance, Lemma 10.36.8 [here](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/037B)), so $\mathcal{O}_K[x]$ is integrally closed.  It follows that $f(x)\in\mathcal{O}_K[x]$.